# Apache Common Document root , Different virtual Host, Different accessible files

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

I had my LFCE exam and i stacked  on a question. Question requested to have 
 apache2 installed with 2 virtual host. site1.example.com and site2.example.com. Both virtual hosts **share the Document Root /var/www/html/.** . also requested to have 2 different files in document root. test_page1.html and test_page2.html and request the file test_page1.html is accessible only from the site1.example.com virtual host and test_page2.html is accessible only from site2.example.com.

My problem was how to secure the test_page1.html will be not accessible from virtual host 2 and vice versa if they share the same Document root.

Virtual host 1

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site1.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
<Directory /var/www/html/> 
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Virtual host 2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site2.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
<Directory /var/www/html/> 
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What are the configurations on your virtualhosts? What are the errors that you are seeing?

Comment: Hello, I have no errors, i had a very specific question. how to secure the test_page1.html will be not accessible from virtual host 2 and vice versa if they share the same Document root.

Comment: @Vlastimil i added virtual hosts

Comment: Check the fine docs which directives can be used in a VirtualHost context, in particular Location, Files, and Directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question for future referral. It can be done with a combination of *Location* block, *regular expressions* and *server variables*.

Create a new config file

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/secure.conf
```

Add:

```
<Location /test_page1.html>
    <If "!(%{SERVER_NAME} -strmatch 'site1.example.com*')">
    Require all denied
    </If>
</Location>
<Location /test_page2.html>
    <If "!(%{SERVER_NAME} -strmatch 'site2.example.com*')">
    Require all denied
    </If>
</Location>
```

enable the config and restart apache:

```
 a2ensite secure
 systemctl restart apache2
```